# Any stable web ui/tool to manage high-availability php-apache-mariadb cluster?

Tags: object

Searched google. Looked at so many options, The best was Rancher.com But still there is no clear way I could find to implement this setup with docker in scalable and load balanced way, So here is my best try now. Docker 1.2 has some volume improvements and glusterFS looks not maintained in proper.

So here is my setup I want to be scalable and highly available. Can any one suggest any webUI tested to implement this kind of setup. web based GUI are more then welcome as Docker-compose/docker etc are developing new APIs regularly in every release and it is preferred to have consistent UI handling that all in back.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but tags are not saving, it just converts to object. I was trying "cluster, docker, docker-compose, rancher, galera"

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*